# React Native Axios timeout when posting to API on remote server (Only on Android device)

Tags: react-native, axios, timeout, android-10.0

**Server**

We have a backend that is connecting to a SOAP server and translating it to REST. The SOAP server can only be connected via VPN.

**App**

1. React-native @0.61.4
2. Axios @0.19.2
3. Android version 10 on device

When running backend on local, API calls work fine both on Emulator and Android device.

But when we deployed the backend on a remote server, the Android device timeout (15 seconds) when trying to make a request.

Couple of suggested solutions online that I tried, and still got nothing working, were:

**1**.Create `network_security_config.xml` and link it on `AndroidManifest.xml` with `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`.

I also tried the solution below without the `base-config`, having just `domain-config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">remove_server_ip_address_here</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**2**. Adding both `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` `tools:targetApi="28"`/`tools:targetApi="29"` to `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also tried just adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` without the `tools:targetApi`

**3**. Tried adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` `android:targetSandboxVersion="1"` to the root element of `AndroidManifest.xml`

---

Keep in mind I do have both `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

Again the request only timeout when trying to post to remote server on an IP address, and it only doesnt work on Android device, everything works fine on Emulator.

Please help, Im not sure what to try anymore!

Answer (score 0):

So if you have a similar problem, it turns out that from Android 9 your server needs SSL otherwise the API calls wont work.

My problem had nothing to do with android build settings.